# How to make a scrollable bootstrap table 100% height?

Tags: html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

Here is a link to the repo:

https://github.com/MoviesAroundMe/MoviesAroundMe2/tree/viewTemplate

We have a table:

```
  <table class="table table-hover movie-list-table">
    <tr><td>1</td></tr>
    <tr><td>2</td></tr>
    <tr><td>3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>4</td></tr>
    <tr><td>5</td></tr>
    <tr><td>6</td></tr>
    <tr><td>7</td></tr>
    <tr><td>8</td></tr>
    <tr><td>9</td></tr>
  </table>
```

which takes up roughly 75% of the height of the page, I'm trying to get it so that it stretches the full height (from the header down) of the page.

I tried:

```
html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  min-height: 100%;
}
```

which successfully makes the body full height but the table didn't auto stretch to fill that space..

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you use flexbox instead of tables?

Answer (score 7):

Why not set the table height using [viewport percentage lengths](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/length#Viewport-percentage_lengths)?

```
table{
   height:100vh;
}
```

> Viewport-percentage lengths defined a length relatively to the size of
>   viewport, that is the visible portion of the document.

Alternatively, from the provided code, the table height is not being set- so you may want to add `height:100%` (as well as to `body`) if you dont feel like using `vh`.

Again, without seeing more code, its hard to provide a more tailored solution, another approach would be to do:

```
body{
   height:100%;
   position:relative;
}
table{
   position:absolute;
   top:0;
   bottom:0;
}
```

On the assumption the table is a direct child of the `body`

Comment: No luck with either viewport nor height 100%, it doesn't budge.

Comment: Can you post a self contained example in the question? Its not possible to reproduce using the present code (without wading through GitHub)

Comment: percent height on block elements only works either if it is absolute positioned or when parent has fixed height so 100% only won't work

Comment: @SW4 https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/ Althought this doesn't truly reflect what's on the page unfortunately. Are there any better solutions than jsfiddle?

Oh and I tried the top:0 bottom:0 approach, which stretches it to the bottom but totally breaks it and makes it look horrible :(

Comment: Yes, Bootply is specially for BT. Even on including the bootstrap class, on jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/qgk1tbn9/1/, or using bootply http://www.bootply.com/IWJCKWTMOj, it seems to works, maybe have you a custom css who doesn't works with...